# Cognos8. UT-DEF-0114 Cannot open lock file

Tags: cognos, lockfile, cognos-8

I have cognos8.4.1 installed. I have authentication defined(LDAP). Everything was working fine, now suddenly I am facing a strange error while executing reports.
UT-DEF-0114 Cannot open lock file: '../bin/../data/cqe/RTModels/URLID1d1XMTk4MToxMzA5NTA3OTk1ODQzOjUyMjQ1o1X1e20111i071i01T101l131l151j9400000Z.rtm.LCK'

Can any one please help me out with this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest:

1. Shutdown cognos
2. Remove the lock file
3. Restart cognos

If you're on a unix / linux system, you might want to look at the owner of these files (and make sure you're running cognos as the intended user)

Comment: Yeap, it's what I did. It happen more than twice. My questions are: why's happening? and how i can avoid?

Comment: Is there any chance you're accidentally starting more than one instance of Cognos on this server...?